# Rails 5 login glitch in authorization using bcrypt

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-5

I followed a handy tutorial on authentication in rails 5 without using the devise gem (tutorial [here](https://gist.github.com/thebucknerlife/10090014))

It appears that immediately after signing out, the user is redirected_to '/login', from which the user *cannot* immediately sign back in. If they refresh the page, no problems - authentication works as normal, but without navigating away and then back to /login or refreshing the page, the user cannot immediately enter their credentials and log back in. Instead, when they enter their credentials and hit 'Submit', nothing at all happens (the credentials stay in the fields, the button looks like it's been clicked, but nothing else happens)

Here is the relevant code from the sessions controller (the same as Step 13 from the tutorial)

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    # If the user exists AND the password entered is correct.
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      # Save the user id inside the browser cookie. This is how we keep the user 
      # logged in when they navigate around our website.
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to '/'
    else
    # If user's login doesn't work, send them back to the login form.
      redirect_to '/login'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to '/login'
  end
```

Note: the tutorial says Rails 4, yet I am using rails 5, in which everything seems to work the same with one small exception; I had to change before_filter to before_action

Comment: when you say 'cannot immediately sign back in', what do you actually mean? 'Sign in' action doesn't work, throws an error or something else?

Comment: When the user enters his/her credentials and clicks 'submit', the credential fields stay full (i.e. the contents doesn't seem to disappear) but nothing happens (normally the user would login and be redirected to a dashboard)

Comment: not sure completely why, looks fine but try to replace `session[:user_id] = nil` with `reset_session`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

In case it's of use to anyone, I was able to fix this by turning off turbolinks in the links:

In application.html.erb, replace
`<%= link_to "Logout", '/logout' %>`

With
`<%= link_to "Logout", '/logout', data: { turbolinks: false } %>`